# Print String Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, initialization, string-literals

This is an array of strings in C language. I try to print the elements, but the program doesn't print them. What is the error in the code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char day[7]={"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"};
 
    printf("%s\n", day[0]);
}
```

Comment: No, that is not an array of strings. It is an array of characters. ```day[0]``` evaluates to a ```char```, but the format specifier ```%s``` expects a ```char *```.

Comment: Voting to close as in need of debug details. Even *trying* to run this through a compiler would have pointed you at the place where you're going wrong.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using? Modern gcc refuses to compile that, even when turning off warnings/errors. Oldest gcc i tried it on was 4.1.2, (released 15 years ago), and even that refused. If you didn't get any errors, I strongly advice to upgrade.

Comment: Even if the compiler does not right away refuse to compile, you should get some warnings from your compiler: "Making integer value from pointer without a cast", "Type mismatch between format specifier %s which expects `char*` and provided argument of type `char`". Did you ignore all these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
char day[7];
```

declares an array of `char`s, which can only accommodate 7 bytes — including the null-terminator if it's a string — not 7 strings of indeterminate length.

You can instead declare an array of pointers to `char`, or `char *`s, where each pointer points to a sequence of `char`s in memory.

```
const char *day[7] = {"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
```

In memory, it will look something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
day[0] -> | "Saturday"
--------------------------------------
day[1] -> | "Sunday"
--------------------------------------
day[2] -> | "Monday"
--------------------------------------
day[3] -> | "Tuesday"
--------------------------------------
day[4] -> | "Wednesday"
--------------------------------------
day[5] -> | "Thursday"
--------------------------------------
day[6] -> | "Friday"
--------------------------------------
```

As `day` is an array of pointers, you can make it's elements (i.e. pointers) point to somewhere else in memory, but you can't change the string literals themselves.

Comment: Thank You very much It's working with me, but if I Want to use Scanf there is an error:                                                                                            int x;
  
     scanf("%d",&x);   
    printf("%s",day[x]);

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I enter the value, but it does not give me the value from the array

Comment: int x;

     scanf("%d",&x);   
    printf("%s",day[x]);

Comment: How have you declared ```day```? What input did you provide? Did it compile without any warnings?

Comment: It is continue with the above code

Comment: You didn't answer the questions. Kindly restate, what do you mean by it is continue with the above code? How have you declared ```day```? What input did you provide? Did the code compile without any warnings?

Comment: @ÖMER you should always check the return value of `scanf`. Did it scan your input correctly? You are not supposed to use `x` if `scanf` returns anything else than `1` for that call.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
char day[7]={"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"};
```

is invalid.

There is not declared an array of strings. There is declared an array of 7 characters that are initialized by addresses of string literals.

The compiler should issue a message relative to this declaration because there is no implicit conversion from the type `char *` (the type of the initializing expressions) to the type `char`.

Instead you should declare a one-dimensional array of pointers like

```
char * day[7] = {"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"};
```

or better like

```
const char * day[7] = {"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"};
```

because you may not change string literals (though in C opposite to C++ string literals have types of non-constant character arrays)

In these declarations the string literals having array types are implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters.

Or a two-dimensional array like

```
char day[7][10] = {"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"};
```

In this declaration all characters including the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literals are used to explicitly initialize elements of the declared array. All characters of the array that do not have a corresponding explicit initializer will be zero initialized.